# Add pagination to simple blog written in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, blogs

I have written a simple database display controller with codeigniter, and am attempting to add pagination. The controller gets info from a database (its very small so there is no need for a model) and sends it to a view for display with pagination. The pagination links display but for some reason the database info is not showing up. I keep getting this error:
Resource id #7   Resource id #13

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: views/blog_view.php

Line Number: 12

<--- database structure --->

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
`city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`state_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
 KEY `idx_state_code` (`state_code`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

<---site controller--->

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');
    $config['base_url'] =     'http://localhost:8888/pagination/index.php/site/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('cities')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 20;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('cities', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->view('data_view',$data);
 }
}
?>
```

<--- data_view --->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Display Database info</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

<?foreach($records as $item):?>
    <?php echo $item; ?>
<?endforeach?>

<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

<!-- Enable responsive features in IE8 with Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) -->
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Follow the tutorials, Try to do it by yourself, come back here with specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call result() on that query.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');
    $config['base_url'] =     'http://localhost:8888/pagination/index.php/site/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('cities')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 20;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $query = $this->db->get('cities', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['records'] = $query->result();

    $query->free_result();

    $this->load->view('data_view',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated code, you must call to result() method and specify the field name too.

```
<?foreach($records->result() as $item):?>
    <?php echo $item->city; ?>
<?endforeach?>
```